# Passing Exception to Crittercism LogHandledException causes NullReferenceException

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, crittercism

Using Assembly CrittercismWP8SDK.dll, v2.0.0.0

In Old code below, Crittercism throws an NullReferenceException: at

[System.NullReferenceException] = {System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at CrittercismSDK.DataContracts.ExceptionObject..ctor(String exceptionName, String exceptionReason, String stacktrace)
   at CrittercismSDK.Crittercism.LogHandledExce...

StackTrace = "   at CrittercismSDK.DataContracts.ExceptionObject..ctor(String exceptionName, String exceptionReason, String stacktrace)\r\n
   at CrittercismSDK.Crittercism.LogHandledException(Exception e)\r\n

Old code

```
Exception exception = new Exception(description);  
exception.Data.Add(MethodName, methodName); 
Crittercism.LogHandledException(exception);  //NullReferenceException
```

New code, no exception:

```
try
{
    Exception ex = new Exception(description);
    ex.Data.Add(MethodName, methodName);
    throw ex;
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    Crittercism.LogHandledException(e);  //No NullReferenceException 
}
```

My theory is that the system populates the Exception object in a way I cannot or that I have missed. Any ideas why the Old code causes Crittercism to throw a NullReferenceException?

Comment: No, there are no Null values passed into Crittercism.

Comment: My bad, I changed NPE to NullReferenceException, which is the actual Exception thrown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creating the Exception this way

```
Exception exception = new Exception(description);  
exception.Data.Add(MethodName, methodName); 
Crittercism.LogHandledException(exception);
```

and passing it directly to Crittercism results in that the `StackTrace`-Property of the exception is set to `null`. Which I think is the problem for Crittercism in this case.

In the catch block the `StackTrace`-property initialize so that Crittercism will not throw a NullReferenceException in this case.

Comment: Thanks gents, I've filed a bug for Crittercism. We'll confirm this and put out a fix. It's true that the more accurate way of sending an exception is certainly throwing it from within a try/catch block as you get the stack trace included.

Comment: A couple things: 1. Both the answers are the same. Can I accept both or only one? I assume the first to get there is the one I accept?        2. I will accept tomorrow to give time for confirmation. There's no way I can tell absolutely that this is the case. But it sounds right.

Comment: @ezaspi you can only accept one answer and it is up to you which answer provides you the best information and answers you question.

Comment: Well Lorentz was first (by a minute or slightly more) but this answer is a bit more informative in that it mentions the catch block.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't throw an Exception, just new it up, the stacktrace is null